# 5 column layout with elements in the middle centered

Tags: android, layout, center

I want to display a list with game scores in my Android app. The list should look like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image above I have 5 view elements per row:

1. First team name
2. First team flag
3. Game score
4. Second team flag
5. Second team name

Elements 2, 3 and 4 should always be centered in the middle of the row so that the colons and flags of the games are directly above/below each other while the length of the team names can vary.

So far I have experimented with RelativeLayout, TableLayout and LinearLayouts but could not find a working solution.

What would be the best approach to reach the desried layout? The layout should work with Android 1.6, vertical and horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with RelativeLayouts I managed to find the following solution which works in portrait and landscape mode.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamAName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/innerlayout"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:text="Team A"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/innerlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/score"
            android:src="@drawable/de" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:background="@drawable/scorebox"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:paddingRight="6dip"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/score"
            android:src="@drawable/de" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamBName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/innerlayout"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Team B"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

A row could look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:text="Team A" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 : 2" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="Team B" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If the ratio between the center object and the two on the sides is not the right one, try changing the value of the `layout_weight`.

Comment: After closer inspection this approach does not work with team names of different lengths. I managed to find a solution working with relative layouts, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

listItem.xml for customAdapter can be like :

```
<RelativeLayot>
 <TextView TeamA alignParentLeft />
 <RelativeLayot alignParentcenter>
   <ImageView flag1   alignParentLeft />
   <TextView 1.2   alignParentcenter />
   <ImageView flag2  alignParentRight />
 </RelativeLayot>
 <TextView TeamB alignParentReight/>
</RelativeLayot>
```

Comment: That is the right direction, but alignParent for the inner RelativeLayout does not work. Still I managed to find a working solution using RelativeLayouts, please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

try it friend:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTeam1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFlag1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScore"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFlag2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTeam2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and you edit the XXdp ;)